# Virtual Host 2 Without www redirects to virtual host 1

Tags: linux, apache, unix, virtualhost, httpd.conf

my httpd.conf looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/host1.com
    ServerName   host1.com
    ServerAlias  www.host1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/host1.com/subdomain
    ServerName   subdomain.host1.com
    ServerAlias  www.subdomain.host1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/host2.com
    ServerName   host2.com
    ServerAlias  www.host2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

So, everything works like it should except:

host2.com shows /var/www/host1.com/

whereas

www.host2.com shows /var/www/host2.com/

I'm pretty sure this is an Apache config problem, but I can't figure it out. Any help??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try in this way

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/host2.com
ServerName   www.host2.com
ServerAlias  *.host2.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/host.com
ServerName   host.com
ServerAlias  *.host.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have DNS FQDN or CNAME configure properly for www ?

```
www.host2.com
host2.com
```

Answer (score 0):

for windows, in hosts file 
127.0.0.1 host2.com
127.0.0.1 www.host2.com

point both to same ip and your configuration works fine.